# how to get the end point of a translated QPolygon

Tags: qt, qpainter, qpolygon

I'm trying to draw an arrow so I just referred to the example code where we can draw arrows:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-edge-cpp.html

I decided to draw using the same formula and tried like:

```
theCurrentLine->setP1(QPointF(0, 0)  );
theCurrentLine->setP2((theLineVector));
p->drawLine(*theCurrentLine);

double angle = ::acos(theCurrentLine->dx() / theCurrentLine->length());
if (theCurrentLine->dy() >= 0)
    angle = TwoPi - angle;

QPointF sourcePoint = QPointF(0,0);

QPointF sourceArrowP1 = sourcePoint + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi / 3) * theArrowSize,
                                              cos(angle + Pi / 3) * theArrowSize);
QPointF sourceArrowP2 = sourcePoint + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * theArrowSize,
                                              cos(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * theArrowSize);

p->drawPolygon(QPolygonF() << theCurrentLine->p1() << sourceArrowP1 << sourceArrowP2);
```

but now I want to draw the line after the arrow head polygon gets drawn.

How can I change the `P1()` value of the `theCurrentLine` which can start after the polygon as currently the `polygon(arrowHead)` and the line start at the same point? I need to start the line after the arrow head is drawn. The reason is sometimes if the pen width increases the arrow head looks smaller than the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the point at index in QPolygon.

```
 QPoint QPolygon::point ( int index ) const
```

It would be easy when you know how many points there are. And Qt documentation is your friend.

And you could use count(), for example:

```
 QPoint lastPoint = myPolygon.point(myPolygon.count() - 1);
```

Just give a name to your polygon, and you'll be fine.

Edit: **Latest version of these codes should solve your problem.** I thought I need to give an example. **You need to add the points in this order:**

```
 QPolygon myPolygon;
 myPolygon.setPoint(0, sourceArrowP1);
 myPolygon.setPoint(1, theCurrentLine->p1());
 myPolygon.setPoint(2, sourceArrowP2);
 p->drawPolygon(myPolygon);
 QPoint lastPoint;
 lastPoint = myPolygon.point(myPolygon.count() - 1);
```

You need to draw the line between **last and first** points. Here:

```
 p->drawLine(myPolygon.point(0, myPolygon.point(myPolygon.count() - 1));
```

If you want your arrow head to be filled with color, you need to use QPainterPath instead of QPolygon:

```
 QPen pen(Qt::black); //Or whatever color you want
 pen.setWidthF(10); //Or whatever size you want your lines to be
 QBrush brush(Qt::red); //Or whatever color you want to fill the arrow head
 p->setPen(pen);
 p->setBrush(brush);
 QPainterPath arrow(sourceArrowP1);
 arrow.lineTo(theCurrentLine->p1());
 arrow.lineTo(sourceArrowP2);
 arrow.lineTo(sourceArrowP1); //This returns to the first point. You might eliminate this line if you want to.
 p->drawPath(arrow);
```

Comment: thanks for the useful post  . i have one more task . i need to draw the line between the last point and the previous to last point.  like middle of the arrow head .

Comment: @Wagmare No problem. Just be sure to look at Qt Documentation often for your answers. It's the best documentation I saw.

Answer (score 0):

My actual implementation:

```
theCurrentLine->setP1(QPointF(0, 0)  );  // arrow line coordinates
theCurrentLine->setP2((theLineVector));
double angle = ::acos(theCurrentLine->dx() / theCurrentLine->length());  // angle of the current Line
if (theCurrentLine->dy() >= 0)
    angle = TwoPi - angle;

// getting arrow head points to be drawn
QPointF sourcePoint = QPointF(0,0);

QPointF sourceArrowP1 = sourcePoint + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi / 3) * theArrowSize,
                                              cos(angle + Pi / 3) * theArrowSize);
QPointF sourceArrowP2 = sourcePoint + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * theArrowSize,
                                              cos(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * theArrowSize);

p->drawPolygon(QPolygonF() << theCurrentLine->p1() << sourceArrowP1 << sourceArrowP2);

// to find the center point in the arrow head right
QLineF perpLine = QLineF(theCurrentLine->p1(), theCurrentLine->p2());
QLineF arrowheadWidth = QLineF(sourceArrowP1, sourceArrowP2);

QPointF originPoint;
QLineF::IntersectType res = perpLine.intersect(arrowheadWidth, &originPoint);

theCurrentLine->setP1(originPoint);
p->drawLine(*theCurrentLine);
```

If anyone knows a much better way to implement this (I'm sure there will be), please correct me.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your comment, but I guess you haven't seen it.

Comment: The problem with my answer is I added the points in the order you gave. What should I do is add the currentLine->p1() as the second point. Then my answer would apply to your situation. I will edit the first code.

Comment: See my answer now, and please comment if there's a problem.

Comment: I added an example with QPainterPath also. You might want to check it out.